# How to locate the US zipcodes at the boundary of a state, say Wisconsin

Tags: zip-codes, boundaries

I would like to identify all the zipcodes at the boundary of a certain state. For example, 53566 Monroe belongs to the southern boundary of Wisconsin.

I am wondering if there is any way to do this in ArcGIS or other software. Is there any database that is dedicated to this issue?

Comment: Generally speaking this is possible, a simple intersection based on "touches" should suffice. Still, it depends on the data you can use. Please expand on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need two datasets:

1. US zip code areas - the actual zip code areas are only available as a very expensive subscription service from the US Postal Service. However, you can probably make do with the zip code tabulation areas (ZCTAs) from the Census Bureau. ZCTAs are updated every ten years; the current ZCTAs are from 2010 (after the 2020 census data comes out, the 2020 ZCTAs will be the current ones). https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/zcta-regions-in-census-files
2. US State boundary *lines* (if you have state polygons, convert them to lines)

Next, select the boundary line of the state that you're interested in. Use the intersection tool to get the zip code areas that *touch* the selected state boundary.

If you just want a list of zip codes, copy and paste the attributes of the selected features from the attribute table into a spreadsheet or text file.